# How to pass database saved link to the anchor tag by using MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Saved a link in database and then i need to view that link in view in asp.net mvc for example `https://www.google.com`

```
<a href="@Url.Content(model.linkurl)" class="contact"> </a>
```

Comment: Where are you facing a problem? Are you getting a link in model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just print the URL:

```
<a href="@model.linkurl">...</a>
```

The `@Url` helpers are for links pointing into the application.